# what are the entity relationships?

Tags: mysql

I am not sure whether this is a 1:M relationship or 1:1 A player plays in a single team in a given season. I think this looks like a 1:1 relationship. and the next one is A coach coaches one or more teams per seasons, but at most 2. so this one is  a 1:M relationship but not sure any help?

I created the entity model but I think it is wrong.

Comment: A team has many players and one coach. A player has one team. A coach has many teams. Type it out in plain language like that and the answers become clear.

Comment: (In the long run, this gets a bit more complicated over multiple seasons, where coaches and players might move between teams. I presume you're not supposed to manage that in this assignment.)

Answer (score 0):

A player can only play with one single team in the given season, that is a one-to-one relationship within that season.

Since a coach can be involved with more than one team, then the coach to team relationship is one-to-many.

You were absolutely on the right track, just lay it out in plain language and you can see what relationships make sense.